# How to extract ID from WP_POST table by POST_PARENT ID and POST_TYPE in WordPress?

Tags: sql, wordpress

How to  extract ID from WP_POST table by POST_PARENT ID and POST_TYPE in WordPress?

[Plese see this image for better understanding >> Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZf3q.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot image, we have extracted the post id. you can use this code.

```
<?php
// Table Name Define
$posts_table = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';

// Get result wp_posts table using table column
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT `ID`, `post_parent`, `post_type` FROM $posts_table WHERE 1 ");

// This loop print the data
foreach($result as $post_data){

//filter data have a post_parent id and post_type.
if($post_data->post_type === 'lesson' || $post_data->post_parent === '12'){
    // print the post id
    echo $post_data->ID;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Dear sir, I need to updated users postmeta, I have course Ids.... I need to get ancestors of course ids, i, e topics , lesson, assignment..... How can I achieve that? ....... I need topic ids (PARENT), THEN LESSON IDS, THEN QUIZ IDS, THEN ASSIGNMENT IDS(IF UPDATED) .....